# ViewPager: Refresh fragment views on user swipe

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have my `MainActivity` use `viewPager` and instantiate two `fragment` views on user swipe gesture. One of the fragments get some data from the server and update its views.

The problem:

Starting the app with no internet connectivity, `fragment` A updates with some dummy data, but then upon switching the Wi-Fi while the app is running and swiping to that fragment doesn't update the fragment with received data.

Please suggest how `fragment` views can be updated after they are instantiated.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
         switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return fragment1.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return fragment3.newInstance();
            default:
                return fragment1.newInstance();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      // Show 2 total pages.
       return 2; 
    }
}
```

FragmentA class(Fragment3 in the code) is given as follows:

```
public class fragment3 extends Fragment implements YourFragmentInterface{

    public static ListView mylistView;
    public static ConfessionsAdapter adapter;
    public static ArrayList<Confession> confessionList;

    public static Context context;

    public static fragment3 newInstance() {

        fragment3 fragment = new fragment3();

        new HttpGetReq().execute("http://example.com");

        return fragment;
    }

    public fragment3() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = getActivity(); // Getting context to tell async task about it, so it can SET stuff here.

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        mylistView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        new HttpGetReq().execute("http://example.com");

        return view;
    }
}
```

The `HttpGetReq` class is an `AsyncTask`, that gets data from the server, parses JSON and updates the fragmentA's `list` in `doInBackground()` method, and then sets adapter to fragmentA's list `View` in its `onPostExecute()` method.

Answer (score 1):

First of create a method which will check your internet connectivity .  For me I have created a class called Utils , and in that class there is method which will return true , if internet is available

```
public class Utils {

    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                    context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            // if no network is available networkInfo will be null
            // otherwise check if we are connected
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Now create a `Broadcast Receiver` , which will notify you when internet connection status is changed . And if it is changed to internet available then it will send a broadcast by local `broadcast manager`

Here is the code for Broadcast receiver ,

```
public class NetworkChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context))
        {
            //sending local broadcast
            Intent i = new Intent("net_connected");
            i.putExtra("message", true);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);

        }
    }
}
```

And in `manifest`  register your receiver

```
  <receiver android:name=".NetworkChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

And then in your activity  register your local broadcast receiver , you should do it in `onResume` and unregister it in `onPause` like this

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    }
```

and write the function of your local broadcast receiver  in fragment

```
   private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                boolean isConnectTed = intent.getBooleanExtra("net_connected",false);
                if(isConnectTed){
                 //if connected then notify to the 
                 mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
```